# Golang http: panic serving: close of closed channel

Tags: go

Trying to clean up my code, the code in `GetDecisListeners()` was previously inside `LiveDecision()` without panic error.

```
//GetDecisListener return listener subscribed to channels
func GetDecisListener(dStructs map[string]map[string]interface{}) (chan interface{}, error) {
    listener := make(chan interface{})
    for r, _ := range dStructs {
        DecisChannels[r].Register(listener)
        key := r
        defer func() {
            Decision(key).Unregister(listener)
            close(listener)
        }()
        fmt.Printf("Done %v\n", r)
    }
    fmt.Print("Done inside\n")
    return listener, nil
}
func LiveDecision(ctx *gin.Context) {
    ...
    listener, err := GetDecisListener(dStructs)
    fmt.Print("Done outside\n")    // cannot reach here
    if err != nil {return}

    ctx.Stream(func(w io.Writer) bool {
        select {
        case msg := <-listener:
            return true
            ...
    }}
}
```

`dStructs` is just an 2D interface map; `Decision` and `DecisChannels` are referred from [here](https://github.com/gin-gonic/examples/blob/master/realtime-advanced/rooms.go).

```
var DecisChannels = make(map[string]broadcast.Broadcaster)
var DecisCols = make(map[string]string)

func OpenListener(decisid string) chan interface{} {
    ite := make(chan interface{})
    Decision(decisid).Register(ite)
    return ite
}

func CloseListener(decisid string, ite chan interface{}) {
    Decision(decisid).Unregister(ite)
    close(ite)
}

func Decision(decisid string) broadcast.Broadcaster {
    b, ok := DecisChannels[decisid]
    if !ok {
        b = broadcast.NewBroadcaster(10)
        DecisChannels[decisid] = b
    }
    return b
}
```

The log shows it hadn't reach `Done outside` but shows `http:panic` after the `GetDecisListener()`.

```
Done item1
Done item2
Done item3
Done item4
Done inside
2021/09/14 14:50:45 http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:39450: close of closed channel
goroutine 40 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc0000c4280)
        /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/net/http/server.go:1767 +0x139
panic(0xd271c0, 0xf5c2b0)
        /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/runtime/panic.go:679 +0x1b2
somewhere/internal/app/route/client.GetDecisListener.func1(0xc0001d8290, 0xe, 0xc0003660c0)
        elsewhere/internal/app/route/client/client.go:42 +0x68
panic(0xd271c0, 0xf5c2b0)
        /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/runtime/panic.go:679 +0x1b2
somewhere/internal/app/route/client.GetDecisListener.func1(0xc0001d8300, 0xd, 0xc0003660c0)
        elsewhere/internal/app/route/client/client.go:42 +0x68
panic(0xd271c0, 0xf5c2b0)
        /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/runtime/panic.go:679 +0x1b2
somewhere/internal/app/route/client.GetDecisListener.func1(0xc0001d8390, 0xd, 0xc0003660c0)
        elsewhere/internal/app/route/client/client.go:42 +0x68
somewhere/internal/app/route/client.GetDecisListener(0xc0001228a0, 0xc0003660c0, 0x0, 0x0)
        elsewhere/internal/app/route/client/client.go:47 +0x27f
somewhere/internal/app/route/client.LiveDecision(0xc0000f8200)
        elsewhere/internal/app/route/client/client.go:77 +0xb0
github.com/gin-gonic/gin.(*Context).Next(0xc0000f8200)
        /home/simon/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.7.4/context.go:165 +0x3b
github.com/gin-gonic/gin.(*Engine).handleHTTPRequest(0xc000470000, 0xc0000f8200)
        /home/simon/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.7.4/gin.go:489 +0x614
github.com/gin-gonic/gin.(*Engine).ServeHTTP(0xc000470000, 0xf7cdc0, 0xc0001020e0, 0xc0000f8100)
        /home/simon/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.7.4/gin.go:445 +0x15d
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc00046e0e0, 0xf7cdc0, 0xc0001020e0, 0xc0000f8100)
        /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/net/http/server.go:2802 +0xa4
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc0000c4280, 0xf7ff00, 0xc00004a040)
        /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/net/http/server.go:1890 +0x875
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
        /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/net/http/server.go:2928 +0x384
```

I suspect `defer func()` of the `Decision(key)` causing the panic. I would have no idea where to put it if this is the case.

Comment: You need to close and unregister your listener somewhere else, right now `GetDecisListener` is returning a closed channel.

Comment: oh...i see....the listeners are closed once it left GetDecisListener()...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot close a channel twice: it will panic.

```
listener := make(chan interface{})
for r, _ := range dStructs {
    DecisChannels[r].Register(listener)
    key := r
    defer func() {
        Decision(key).Unregister(listener)
        close(listener)
    }()
    fmt.Printf("Done %v\n", r)
}
```

Here if `len(dStructs) > 1`, two defered call will try to close `listener`

Maybe you can do something like:

```
listener := make(chan interface{})
shouldClose := false
for r, _ := range dStructs {
    DecisChannels[r].Register(listener)
    key := r
    defer func() {
        Decision(key).Unregister(listener)
    }()
    shouldClose = true
    fmt.Printf("Done %v\n", r)
}
if shouldClose {
    close(listener)    
}
```

Comment: ok thanks, looks like the defer of `close(listener)` should be added after its declaration. And no point pulling these codes out of `LiveDecision()`